# Data Copy From one db server to another db server in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ftp

For auditing purpose i need to copy data from one MYSQL db server to another.
I don't want following solutions

1.<strike>mysqldump</strike>

2.<strike>Select from one location and insert to another</strike>

And my requirements are

1.Data transfer should be fast

2.Structure of both db is different

plz suggest some options

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of ORM? Hibernate maybe?. All in all workflow should be the same no mather how are you going to achieve this and is as follows:

1. Fetch some data from source DB(maybe single row with it's all associations.
2. Transform data into new database model
3. Save new modeled data into new database.

For fast transfer I would suggest to dump old DB, and create temporary instance on machine where your new DB server is located. Mysql provides fast serverside transfer od DB dumps between MySQL server instances.

Comment: no i am not using ORM .Are you telling that dumping data in file and restoring on targeted db will be faster than normal Select from one location and insert to another ?

Comment: If you have different models (and you mentioned that you do) then direct transfer is not possible (via direct dump). Speed of such operation will depend on connection speed between process performing data transfer and both databases. If I were you, I would instantiate "old" DB on target DB server so there would be no connection latency issue hit on performance of such transfer - everything would be done locally.

Comment: but i cannot put both dbs on same server due to performance and security reasons

Comment: That you have no other choice that do it remotly to both DBs. Approach is still the same.